# package java.util.function does not exist?

Tags: java, import

I'm a newbie to Java and now learning [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html). When I typed the exactly code in `LabmdaScopeTest.java`, I encountered the error `package java.util.funciton does not exist`. The code is as below.

```
import java.util.funciton.Consumer;

public class LambdaScopeTest {

public int x = 0;

class FirstLevel {

    public int x = 1;

    void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {

        // The following statement causes the complier to generate
        // the error "local variables referenced from a lambda expression
        // must be final or effectively final" in statemen A:
        //
        // x = 99;

        Consumer<Integer> myConsumer = (y) ->
        {
            System.out.println("x = " + x); // statement A
            System.out.println("y = " + y);
            System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
            System.out.println("LambdaScopeTest.this.x = " + 
                LambdaScopeTest.this.x);
        };

        myConsumer.accept(x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LambdaScopeTest st = new LambdaScopeTest();
    LambdaScopeTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
    fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
}
```

}

I commented the `import` statement and replaced the code to `java.util.function.Consumer<Integer> myConsumer` and everything became okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
import java.util.funciton.Consumer;
                     ↑↑
```

should be:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
```

Comment: @Kocko I should be more careful in future, thanks

Comment: @AnnabellChan, you can rely on the IDE to fix the `import` statements for you.

Comment: like IntelliJIDEA, but since I'm a starter, I want to use it after I'm more familiar with the language basics :)